# Bootstrap Dropdown NavBar Button Not Working

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I've been using Bootstrap to make a navbar, and the dropdown button hasn't been doing anything when I click on it. What could be the issue?

```html
<!-- Website HEAD -->

<head>

  <title> Celeb Live </title>

  <!-- Website Meta's -->

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Description" content="Meet Celebrities virtually live around the world!">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="celeblive, Celeb Live, Meet Celeb">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- Website CSS / Bootstrap / FONT AWESOME / AOS -->

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-46r060N2LrChLLb5zowXQ72/iKKNiw/lAmygmHExk/o=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/main.css">

</head>
<!-- Website BODY -->

<body>

  <!-- Website Navbar -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-fixed-top ">
    <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color:#fff; font-size:28px;"></i>
                </span>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Celebs
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
          </a>
          
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" id="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Music celebrities</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Youtube celebrities</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hollywood celebrities</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Events
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" id="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Music artist live events</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Youtuber live events</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hollywood live events</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConstantineLinardakis/TSA-Webmaster-Challenge/main/src/assets/CelebLive.png" alt="CelebLive" height="90" width="100">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">About
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" id="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About the team</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About the program</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link login" href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Website CONTAINER-FLUID (CONTENT) -->

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Website FOOTER -->

  <footer class="page-footer">
    <!-- fixed bottom here if needed and AOS -->
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="footer-copyright">
        © 2021 Copyright:
        <a href="https://constantinelinardakis.github.io/TSA-Webmaster-Challenge/home.html"> CelebLive.com</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Website JS Bootstrap/Popper/AOS -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>

  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>

</body>
```

**My theory :**
I don't know if it is the navbar `data-target`, but changing that seemed to not do anything?

My burger does appear, but it does not have a function to when it is clicked? Could it be a JS problem, or a bad stylesheet link/script link?

Comment: You're missing the `#` on the data target value.

Comment: Also, you've tagged Bootstrap 4, but you've loaded Bootstrap 5 in your demo/site. They have different attribute spelling. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem / Resolution : [Bootstrap 5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/).  `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` in `navbar-toggler`.

Fix :

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
               <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color:#fff; font-size:28px;"></i>
         </span>
</button>
```